# Small home network design

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, switch

I'm setting up a home network and my current architecture looks like this:

cable in → [modem](https://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/cable-modems-routers/CM600.aspx) → [unmanaged 5 port switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BC7QMM).

- (3 ports go to wired devices (synology, mac mini, smarthome hub)
- 1 port goes to another [unmanaged 8 port switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BCC0LO) (to distribute throughout the house). Finally, an [eero router](https://eero.com/shop/home-wifi-system-2-pack) is connected in another part of the house to the eight port switch.

The wifi works great through the Eero. However, when connected to the wifi network - I can't see any of the wired devices on my local network.

My only question is should this setup work as I currently have it laid out? There very well may be some wireless isolation going on with the eero that I haven't found yet, but I just want to make sure this physical setup should work.

Comment: Are all clients part of the same subnet. Your question has conflicting information

Comment: @Ramhound which part is conflicting? - maybe I can describe it better. And I'm not sure if everything is on the same subnet.

Comment: You will need to bridge WLAN to LAN.

Comment: Unless you have an unmanaged 5 port switch and an 8 port switch you have conflicting information in your question.  If you cannot tell us if they are part of the same subnet it sounds like they are not.  Which means it's not unusual you cannot communicate with any device on the network. You need to determine that and update your question.  Commentary deemed unnecessary will be flagged so update your question

Comment: A bit of googling suggested that connecting one switch to another will work fine, but the second switch might be slower on the network than first switch. I think Ramhound and Enzo are talking about the same issue, but have different ideas. I agree more with Enzo, I could be wrong, but some routers seem to create their own subset (what you call wireless isolation), so without Enzo's briding suggestion, WiFi and Ethernet devices will not connect easily. Just be warned I am no expert, and could be wrong about all of this.

Comment: @Ramhound that is correct. From cable to router it looks like this: cable_in → modem → unmanaged 5 port switch → unmanaged 8 port switch → router.

Comment: @user173724 thanks for the tips, I'll definitely check that out!

Comment: @tknickman Be warned, I could be 100% wrong, I have absolutely no experience in this at all, and only spent 10 seconds googling about the switches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...When connected to the wifi network - I can't see any of the wired devices on my local network. My only question is should this setup work as I currently have it laid out?

Yes, as long as the Eero wireless system allows wireless devices to communicate with those on the wired LAN.  However, if the Eero system restricts wireless devices from communicating with any other upstream device besides Eero router's gateway (which would be your Cable modem), then no, this setup won't work for your stated goal.

If the Eero is preventing communication from wireless to wired devices, you have a few options:

1. Plug the Eero router directly into your cable modem, then plug your 5-port switch into one of its wired ports. This makes the Eero router your LAN's "primary" router.
2. Reconfigure the Eero to allow clients connected through it to communicate with devices on your wired LAN.

Comment: I wanted to avoid option 1 since my modem is in a closet and the switch allows my router to be more centrally located in the house - but I'll give both options here a shot. This has answered my questions about if this should work, and under what circumstances. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - Have you tried setting your AP to bridge mode? Bridge your eeros: Open the eero app and tap on the hamburger menu on the top left. Choose ‘Network settings’. Then navigate to ‘Advanced settings’, then tap on ‘DHCP & NAT.’ Check 'Bridge' and tap 'Save' on the top right.

Comment: @tknickman - Bridge mode only if it isn't the device providing DHCP throughout your network.